# i want to save a particular column into a new excel sheet in python

Tags: python, excel

if this is the spread sheet then I want to make a new spreadsheet containing only `product id`:

```py
transaction id product id
1001           1    
1002           2
1003           3
```

the code I have written so far I am able to print a particular column

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
book = Workbook()
x = input("row name")
y=int(x)
book.save("sample.xlsx")
for row in sheet.rows:
     print(row[y].value)
```

Comment: Try this: `df[['prduct_id]].to_excel('product_ids.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')`

Comment: In addition to @ThePyGuy: first load the excel file into a pd.DataFrame: `df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')` .

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on i am relatively new to python and I wanted to use openpyxl for this program instead of pandas. till now i can extract the particular column i want i just want to save that extracted column into a new excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html). Its a lot less complicated:

```
df[['product_id']].to_excel('sample.xlsx', index = False)  #Keeping index = True will have an extra row with index
```